# Angularjs UI Datepicker with ui.mask

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use ui datepicker with ui.mask:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="99.99.9999" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i select date for example 11.11.2015, it shows up in input as 11.20.1500

What am i doing wrong?
Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1lXyWDAig2MRajxMLrLF?p=preview

Comment: Remove `ui-mask="XX.XX.XXXX"`

Comment: And then nothing use `datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"` to format the date, what's the question?

Comment: i want to have both - datepicker and masked input. if user wants he uses datepicker, otherway he types date in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your ui-mask to  `ui-mask="XX.XX.XXXX"` and it should be working fine

Comment: then mask not working. i need masked input with datepicker

Comment: ?? what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: i want to have both - datepicker and masked input. if user wants he uses datepicker, otherway he types date in input.

Comment: ok, sorry didn't get that right, so ... your problem is that when you select a date your ng-model dt = "2015-11-11T07:47:07.798Z"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94896/discussion-between-macrog-and-jack-malkovich).